# split the string by numbers and signs c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split the following string

```
5 + 91 * 6 + 8 - 79
```

and as a result get an array which will save the all elements(including signs) in the same  sequence 
like this `{5, +, 91, *, 6, +, 8, -, 79}`  etc

I can not split it by space, because the string can be like this as well `5 + 91* 6+ 8 -79` or 
without spaces at all `5+91*6+8-79`

I tried this

```
 string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"[\d\+\-\*]{1,}");
```

but it returns nothing on cmd, when I try this

```
foreach (string value in result)
    {

         Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work. What are you getting?

Comment: Just use string.Split(','):
If your data is in str, so it would be like:
string[] elements = str.Split(new[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'});

Comment: Try to include the space as well in there `[\+\-\*\s]{1,}` but remove the `\d`.

Comment: LOL @graumanoz, read the question closer.

Comment: @Jerry in that case it will give my only the numbers as an array, but I will not have the signs, but I need them as well. Thanks

Comment: Oh okay, I'm not so familiar with `Regex.Split` and there was a question a bit like yours some while back. That said, I think that `Regex.Match` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Matches()`:

```
string str = "5 + 91* 6+ 8 -79";

MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+|[\+\-\*]");

foreach (var value in result)
{
     Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

this gives you:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a little Linq:

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+|[\+\-\*]")
                       .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
string[] result = 
    (from m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+|[\+\-\*]").Cast<Match>()
     select m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, only Kai's solution seems easier, I guess because I am beginner in c# :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **split** it with this regex

```
(?<=\d)\s*(?=[+*/-])|(?<=[+*/-])\s*(?=\d)
```

Yes,it's long but it does split the string!